# Online IDE for Python

Tags: python, testing, ide

Is there any web-based IDE that I can use to run quick tests? There're a dozen for PHP and some for even Java but I haven't found yet that runs Python. If there's an **open-source IDE available that I can host and run myself**, that'd be better.

Thanks

Comment: How can it be quicker to use some remote client/server Python than to use your local python?  What's wrong with your local Python?

Comment: Why? convenience and freedom. I want to be able to run quick tests from my iPhone while I'm reading the book ('Learning Python') sitting on my sofa. I don't like to carry my 6 pound MBP everywhere. ;)

Comment: "Convenience"?  Typing code on a iPhone?  Can't see it.

Comment: Yes, but still better than carrying MBP 17" around. :)

Comment: When you say "test" do you really mean "interactive experimentation"?

Comment: Check out [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh). It gives you a full Ubuntu VM with Root in your browser. Meaning that Python2 & 3, and all other Nix languages are supported, and you have the ability to install anything missing from the start :)

Comment: Wonder why Trinket https://trinket.io/ is not in any of the answers. Maybe it wasn't there at the time. But its pretty good. Nice UI/UX.

Comment: Just noting that Pythonista on the iPhone works very well. Have developed code successfully. Replicated to Dropbox means same source files whether from laptop, server, web front-end, or iPhone (sure, add Android :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might want to give a try at:

- [Try Python](http://www.trypython.org/)
- [codepad](http://codepad.org/)
- [codenode](http://codenode.org/)

Comment: First two look great, wish they also supported Python 3 though.

Comment: you might want to look at http://github.com/codenode/codenode source code

Comment: @Nimbuz ideone supports Python 3

Comment: Check out https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace. ML Workspace is an open-source web IDE for Python development that combines Jupyter, VS Code, a Desktop GUI, and many other tools & libraries into one convenient Docker image.

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying out [PythonAnywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) and it has in-browser support for both 3.2 and 2.7.  It also lets you sync to dropbox and deploy right to the web.

Comment: I looks like they are in beta right now. do you have any beta invites to share?

Comment: Just a note from a PythonAnywhere dev to say that we're no longer in beta :-)

Answer (score 5):

These aren't full IDEs but there are a lot of options for online python interpreters:

- http://www.codepad.org
- http://www.ideone.com
- http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit
- http://portablepython.com/
- http://www.pythonanywhere.com/
- http://repl.it/
- http://www.learnpython.org/
- http://labs.codecademy.com/
- http://www.sourcelair.com/
- http://pythonfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Codepad](http://codepad.org) can compile code, if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

http://shell.appspot.com/  The google AppEngine shell (not really an IDE though).

Comment: This application has some problems that make it a poor choice for learning Python. For instance, all objects are immutable. I'd wait for this defect to be resolved before using it.

Comment: I extended the idea with a little editor (Mozilla Skywriter): http://perewe.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

Codecademy has one at [labs.codecademy.com](http://labs.codecademy.com/). It has syntax highlighting and auto indent.

Comment: This is actually Repl.it

Answer (score 2):

Repl.it has a python interpreter and terminal among others. It may not be a full-fledged IDE. I'm not sure how you define that.

Answer (score 1):

Through not specifically for python [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) is good too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that IDE's are the last kind of programs that will ever go web based, because a good IDE needs to be so extremely interactive if it wants to be good.

I really don't see a reason for this and others seem to agree because there isn't any.
And no, an interactive web shell or compiler has nothing to do with an IDE.

Comment: There already are a few online JavaScript IDEs, including http://jsfiddle.net, http://cloud9.io, and http://tinker.io. I think it's already possible for web-based IDEs to be "extremely interactive". Web-based IDEs also tend to be much more portable than desktop-based IDEs.

Comment: Web-based IDEs won't replace my native code editor for the majority of my work, but they're really awesome for sharing bits of code and collaborating with others.

Answer (score 1):

[ideone.com](http://ideone.com) is able to compile and run Python. There is also an integrated web editor - perfect for quick tests. It is not an open source but you can use Ideone API to build your service.

Answer (score 1):

[Repl.it](http://repl.it) is an awesome project, the python engine is completely written in javascript, that means, all the code is executed on user's side, rather than server. Also you can use it offline, once the engine is loaded. It is very fast and light weight

Comment: fast and light weight? it is compiled from c with llvm, so the whole python interpretter is running inside another interpreter resulting replit to be slow...

Answer (score 1):

**[Cloud9](http://c9.io)** is not open-source, but it's probably the best online IDE.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/) is an interesting project ([user guide](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Bespin/UserGuide)).

It is a Mozilla labs open source project to build a browser-based IDE. You can host it yourself, see the [Bespin developer guide](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Bespin/DeveloperGuide).

I don't think it is currently a full-fledged Python IDE, but I believe it could be made into one with a bit of effort. The Bespin server is written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome Python Shell  https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Codenvy](http://codenvy.com) can be a good alternative. You may also find some info at http://bestonlineide.com