# Is it possible to run php code online?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online PHP IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897/online-php-ide)

In php it is possible to run code and get the results online?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Most web servers have a PHP module installed with Apache that allows you to send the output of PHP scripts as an HTTP response (essentially- a website). Is this what you mean?

Comment: I sure hope it is, otherwise quite a few websites are about to become victems of a massive schrödinbug.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897/online-php-ide

Comment: @Tejas: Just letting you know this has been asked before and btw I did not downvote the question.

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040108/opensource-online-ide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869226/is-there-a-place-online-that-i-can-test-my-php-code

Comment: A few more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491721/are-there-any-good-online-ides http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991428/execute-scripts-online

Comment: @Tejas1810: -1. You need to learn **netiquette** before you lean to run PHP online. Also tagging this question and you for admin attention.

Comment: @gameover, There are as many types of netiquette as there are domains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, go to [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) or [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)

Comment: I've used codepad and it's very good.  I also recommend 3v4l.org since you can see how your script behaves in multiple versions of PHP, including the HHVM.

Answer (score 4):

Try [ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/), [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/)

Comment: Ha, well our answers are a little similar! Great minds think alike, yadda yadda :) Have a +1 for being 9 seconds quicker.

Comment: @alex: you are right :) But looks like a duplicate question.

Comment: @Tejas1810: What do you mean? It is the answer to your question. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Yep you can go to codepad.org or trycodeonline.com