# Searching for online Python IDE

Tags: python, ide

Subj.
I seeking IDE with following features:

- Support for Python standart library(at least most of it)
- Support for files and importing modules from files
- Access to network
- Lightweight & fast

Comment: do you really mean an *online* IDE?

Comment: this question is gonna get closed... i bet...

Comment: @JoranBeasley.  As it should.  The question invites too much subjectivity to be useful.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036987/online-ide-for-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) but decided desktop IDEs are more convenient

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it online you can try

http://ideone.com/

There is python online IDE used by udacity, maybe worth to check it too

Comment: lol I was about to post this same link

Answer (score 1):

I used Wingware when I was developing Python for Google App Engine several years ago:

http://wingware.com/

Comment: meh more expensive then eclipse+pydev and less robust ... at least imho

Answer (score 1):

I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com), it is based on Eclipse, but comes out of the box with pydev for Python integration, and is good if you want to develop Django/GAE applications

Comment: this is the best python IDE imho (its teh same as pydev+eclipse) but its just prepackaged for python specifically

Answer (score 1):

ninja ide is lightweight and fast and does all that... and its free

(but Eclipse+PyDev wins hands down for sheer awesomeness and power, but loses on lightweight and fast..)

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for something along the lines of [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Install Eclipse
Install PyDev http://pydev.org/
Enjoy!

Comment: ok good point ... if you have a good computer and solid state drives its fast

Comment: developers should not suffer, ssd is a must. Eclipse framework is pretty lightweight if it doesn't have all the Java DEV BS ontop.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE that ships with Python usually can do it for my use cases. When you first open it you get the repl, but File > New Window will give you a file to edit. Save that file as a .py file and f5 to run.

I think it addresses your lightweight and fast requirement.

Comment: does idle fix inconsistent use of tabs/spaces? thats one of the most useful features in a python ide imho ...

Comment: It uses 4 spaces instead of tabs (when you type a tab), and does a pretty good job indenting. So to answer you I would say it forces (transparently to the user) consistent use of tab/spaces. It will not fix an indent of 5 spaces when you've been using 4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains makes the best IDEs on the market, hands down.  Check out [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: I really like pycharm for django projects... (Is there a way to get linkbacks to where something was defined like in eclipse?(eg hover over class name and be able to link to the class declaration)

Comment: I just type "shift N" and enter the class name.  PyCharm will bring me right to the source.